# How to write location for nginx matching php script in certain path

Tags: regex, nginx

I have an php application migrating to nginx, site structure as follows,

```
|-aaa
|-bbb
|--ccc
|---ccc.php
|---ddd
|----ddd.php
|--eee
|-fff
|-index.php
```

here is my conf

```
location ~ ^/(?!bbb).*\.php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    set $fsn index.php;
    if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
        set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ ^/bbb/ccc/ddd/ {
    index ddd.php;
    allow all;
}

location ~ ^/(bbb) {
    deny  all;
}
```

I can access all php files except ones under bbb folder, I also can access ddd.php file. But ddd.php is not process as php script.

Comment: why havent you used try files instead of index in the line index ddd.php

Comment: does it make any difference? please consider me as a noob on nginx =)

Comment: it is weird that you can access the ddd.php file and still cant process it like a php file. Can you explain this line